# JavaScript Split string and create new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below string

```
"ITEM1","ITEM2","ITEM3","ITEM4","ITEM5","ITEM6","ITEM7"~100000000,1000048,0010041,1,1,1,1~100000001,1000050,,2,0,2,1~100000002,1068832,0010124,1,1,1,1~100000003,1143748,0010165,1,1,1,1~100000004,,0010173,1,2,1,1~100000005,,0010199,2,2,2,1~100000006,,0010215,1,2,1,1~100000007,,0010306,0,2,1,1~100000008,1092546,0010355,1,1,1,1~100000009,1037977,,2,1,2,1~
```

I need to split by `~` and should create separate arrays with double quotes `""`. Below is expected

```
[
    ["ITEM1","ITEM2","ITEM3","ITEM4","ITEM5","ITEM6","ITEM7"],
    ["100000000","1000048","0010041","1","1","1","1"],
    ["100000000","1000048","0010041","1","1","1","1"],
    ["100000000","1000048","0010041","1","1","1","1"],
]
```

This is what i have tried.

```
str.split('~').slice(2)
```

Which does not split to separate arrays. How to achieve the same. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The input makes no sense. Where's the first quote? Why are there quotes at all? Why do you remove the first two elements?

Comment: @Andreas its a typo

Comment: Why is it a string? Where does it come from? Could you just not create an array of items?

Comment: Basically this is series of data which needs to export to a CSV file. This is directly coming from a database. I'm using React to export to CSV. This needs expected format to download to CSV

Comment: You need to split at `~` first, and then loop over the resulting strings, and split those a `,` again. And you will need to add the double quotes you want around the numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first split with `~` and then split each sub array with `,`. The code below is also removing the empty strings `""`. IF you want them included just remove the `.filter(i => i)`

**EDIT:**
removed the empty strings filter

```js
const s = '"ITEM1","ITEM2","ITEM3","ITEM4","ITEM5","ITEM6","ITEM7"~100000000,1000048,0010041,1,1,1,1~100000001,1000050,,2,0,2,1~100000002,1068832,0010124,1,1,1,1~100000003,1143748,0010165,1,1,1,1~100000004,,0010173,1,2,1,1~100000005,,0010199,2,2,2,1~100000006,,0010215,1,2,1,1~100000007,,0010306,0,2,1,1~100000008,1092546,0010355,1,1,1,1~100000009,1037977,,2,1,2,1~'

const arr1 = s.split('~')

const arr2 = arr1.map(arr => {
  arr = arr.replace(/\"/g, '')
  return arr.split(',')
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2, null, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks. But some strings have `100000016,,0010561,1,2,1,1`..  Your code is giving me `['100000016', '0010561', '1', '2', '1', '1']`.  But i need to consider space as well. Like this`['100000016', ' ', '0010561', '1', '2', '1', '1']`

Comment: @Matarishvan Remove `.filter(i => i)` from the return inside `arr1.map` so it would just be `return arr.split(',')`